# Construct struct literal with embedded structs

Tags: go, literals

How do I construct a struct literal with embedded struct?

Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Ping struct {
    Content struct {
        name string
    }
}

func main() {
   p := Ping{Content{"hello"}}
   fmt.Println(p)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/UH4YO6CAFv

This works if I had written the structs this way:

Go:

```
type Ping struct {
   Content
}

type Content struct {
    name string
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/ERGsO4CMEN

How do I do it with the embedded struct version in the first code version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, and you really shouldn't either, but if you insist anyway you can use something like:

```
p := Ping{struct{ name string }{"don't do it"}}
```

or

```
p := Ping{}
p.Content.name = "hello"
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/9B7aaDwXNj)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to be supported, looking at the [spec for Struct type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#StructType)

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an anonymous field, also called an embedded field or an embedding of the type in the struct.
>   **An embedded type must be specified as a type name T** or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not be a pointer type.

That means T must be defined somewhere else.